# c++ how to replace a string in an array for another string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying a short code that uses an array, I basically want to replace the word hate for love when I call my function WordReplace but I keep printing the same thing:

I don't love c++
I don't love c++

I have tried different things but I am not sure what is wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void WordReplace(string*x, int start, int end, string g, string w)
{
   for (int z = start; z <= end; z++)
   {
      if (x[z] == g)
         x[z] == w;

      cout << x[z]<<" ";
   }
}

int main()
{
   string x[4] = {"I", "don't", "hate", "c++"};

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      cout << x[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   WordReplace(x, 0, 3, "hate", "love");

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[z] == w`  should be `x[z] = w`. Read about the difference between `=` and `==` in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: It might also help to give your variable more intuitive names. At least `g` and `w` don't do it for me. But @IgorTandetnik has your answer.

Comment: *I have tried different things* -- Except the `std::replace` algorithm function, which does the job in one line of code.  The point is that if you're writing code that has the feeling that it has to have been done millions of times before (like replacing x with y), then there is more than likely an STL algorithm function that does the job (if not a set of functions).

Comment: Actually gcc 5.1.0 does not produce any warnings. Reason seems to be that operator is overloaded. When `std::string` replaced with `int` warning "statement has no effect" is produced as expected.

Comment: Try using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array.  A lot easier to pass to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a new value to a variable you need the following syntax:

```
myVar = myValue;
```

This will change the value of myVar to myValue.

This construction:

```
myVar == myValue
```

is a comparison and is treated as a bool, since it returned true(if myVar equals myValue) and False (if they are not equal). The construction doesn't change the value of myVar or myValue.

In your case you need to replace `x[z] == w` by `x[z] = w`, as suggested by Igor

Answer (score 5):

Just use [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
std::string x[] = {"I", "don't", "hate", "c++"};
std::replace( std::begin( x ), std::end( x ), "hate", "love" );
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/sfET3o)

Answer (score 2):

You have c++. Use proper containers (e.g. std::vector).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void WordReplace(vector<string> &sentence, string search_string,
             string replace_string) {
    for (auto &word : sentence) {
        if (word == search_string)
            word = replace_string;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> sentence{"I", "don't", "hate", "c++"};

    for (const auto word : sentence)
        cout << word << " ";
    cout << endl;

    WordReplace(sentence, "hate", "love");

    for (const auto word : sentence)
        cout << word << " ";
    cout << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

or even better, don't reinvent the wheel

```
std::vector<std::string> x {"I", "don't", "hate", "c++"};
std::replace( x.begin(), x.end(), "hate", "love" );
```